# How to create an array of references to a class?

Tags: java, arrays, nested-class

The title might be a bit misleading but I can't think of another way to describe it. Let me just show you an example:

```
class SomeClass {
  class Foo {
    class Bar {
      int things = 57;
      String five = "things";
    }
    class OtherBar {
      int things = 42;
      String five = "stuff";
    }
  }
  Object[] references = {Foo.Bar,  Foo.OtherBar};
}
```

Whenever I compile, it gives an error for every item in the array:

```
File.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    Object[] references = {Foo.Bar, Foo.OtherBar};
                              ^
  symbol:   variable Bar
  location: class SomeClass.Foo
```

The answer might be very obvious, but this is my first actual project in Java.

Edit: I shouldn't be using classes to store information. However, I will still take an answer to the question for the future.

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between *classes* and *instances*.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to reference classes themselves or instances of those classes?

Comment: maybe you want Foo.Bar.class?

Comment: I won't have any instances of any of the classes. I tried to use static, but I kept getting errors about accessing static things in a non-static context.

Comment: You must explain what you're trying to accomplish.  Nesting classes 3-deep like this is a sign that you're confusing some basic concepts.

Comment: I'm trying to group similar information, so the outermost class would be general, and the inner classes would be more specific.

Comment: I didn't realize how incorrect what I was doing was until I started explaining it. Actually, I should probably not use classes for the information I'm trying to store.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the inner classes static: `static class Foo`, `static class Bar`, and `static class OtherBar`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class SomeClass {
  ...
  ...
  ...

  Object[] references = {Foo.Bar.class, Foo.OtherBar.class};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Every class has a static field called `class` which represents the class object. For example, you would use `Foo.Bar.class` and `Foo.OtherBar.class`